# Prestashop WebService "limit" parameter not working as expected

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I'm trying to use the *limit* parameter in PrestaShop's WebService.
My problem is it's only half working, the number of entries to display is working fine, but the "starting point" is not.
For example: 
http://example.com/api/combinations?display=[id,reference]&limit=[0,500]&sort=id_ASC&ws_key=WEBSERVICEKEY
AND
http://example.com/api/combinations?display=[id,reference]&limit=[500,500]&sort=id_ASC&ws_key=WEBSERVICEKEY
Returns **exactly** the same products (first 500).

I am using PS 1.6.1.17
I've updated the classes/webservice folder with the latest (from 1.6.1.18).
The code (classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php) - no override:

```
    $sql_limit = '';
    if (isset($this->urlFragments['limit'])) {
        $limitArgs = explode(',', $this->urlFragments['limit']);
        if (count($limitArgs) > 2) {
            $this->setError(400, 'The "limit" value has to be formed as this example: "5,25" or "10"', 39);
            return false;
        } else {
            $sql_limit .= ' LIMIT '.(int)($limitArgs[0]).(isset($limitArgs[1]) ? ', '.(int)($limitArgs[1]) : '')."\n";// LIMIT X|X, Y

        }
    }
```

The code looks fine, maybe it's SQL related? I'd like to print the generated query to test it but I couldn't fin a way...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
The int cast wasn't working here.
**$this->urlFragments['limit']** value is **[500,500]**.
So after explode $limitArgs[0] is equal to **[500** but  the code **(int)($limitArgs[0])** was always giving me **0** instead of **500** as result.
I replaced it with an ugly str_replace as follow:

```
 $sql_limit .= ' LIMIT '.str_replace("[", "", $limitArgs[0]).(isset($limitArgs[1]) ? ','.(int)($limitArgs[1]) : '')."\n";// LIMIT X|X, Y
```

Not the best, but could be usefull if anyone faces this situation.

edit: I posted on the forge, the correct syntax for limit is **limit=X,Y** not limit=[X,Y].